# Python- Prime summands to an even number

Tags: python, primes

This is the assignment my professor gave me. I have no idea where to start or what to do! 
The point is to use loops to figure this out and I can do the loops, but this is blowing my mind.

Even numbers and primes.

A prime number is one that has 1 and itself as its only divisors. 2, 3, 5, 7 and 11 are the first several. Notice 
that 'being prime' is purely a multiplicative condition -- it has nothing to do with addition. So it might be
surprising that if we start listing even numbers, they seem to be the sum (addition!) of two primes. 
4 = 2 + 2, 6 = 3 + 3, 8 = 5 + 3, 10 = 3 + 7, 12 = 7 + 5, 14 = 7 + 7, 16 = 13 + 3, ...

Is this always the case? Can every even number be written as the sum of two primes?

1. Write a is_prime(n) function. 
   It should accept a positive integer n>1 as input, and output True or False, depending on whether n is or is not
   a prime number. Do this with a loop that checks whether for any integer d, 1 < d < sqrt(n), d divides n. 
   I'd suggest a while loop -- think carefully about the conditional for the loop, and when you want to change
   this conditional inside the loop. (Use a boolean for your condition).
2. Write a prime_sum(n) function.
   It should accept an even number n>1 as input, and via a loop search for primes p & q with p + q = n. 
   Hint: start with p = 3. If (p) and (n-p) are prime you are done. If not, set p+=2 and try again.
   Make sure you do not search forever!
3. Main.

   - Ask the user for an even number n. Continually ask them until they do give you a positive even number.
   - Search for the summands p & q, and either print them out (if they exist) or say they don't.
   - Ask the user if they wish to try with another even, and let them continue until they quit.

---

I didn't know I could edit this! :) So this is what I have so far. I have not tested it yet to debug it b/c I want to get it all down and when the errors pop up I will address them, but if you see any immediate problems let me know.

```
def is_prime(n):
    d=2
    while n>1 and d<n**0.5:
        if n%2==0:
            c=False
        d+=1
    return c

def prime_sum(n):
    p=3
    while n>1:
        q=n-p
        if q<=0:
            p+=2
            q=n-p
            is_prime(q)
        else:
            is_prime(q)
            is_prime(p)
    while True:
        print("The prime summands of", n, "are", p, "and", q)
    while False:
        print("There are no prime summands of", n)

def main():
    n=eval(input("Gimme an even number please: "))
    while True:
        n=eval(input("That is not a positive even number. Try again: "))
    #not sure how to combine yet, but I am still finishing.
    #will edit again when I have it all down.
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: "I can do the loops" suggests to me that you understand the prompt, but I guess that's not the case. What exactly in the assignment don't you understand, if not the way to organize the loops?

Comment: What's the question?  You have the steps.  Write the is_prime function.  Then move on to the next step.  We won't do your homework for you.  You have to write your own code.

Comment: Lookup Goldbach Conjecture. It is an unsolved problem.

Comment: "1 < d < sqrt(n)" gives you the starting and ending points for the loop. "checks whether for any integer d, ..., d divides n" gives you what should go inside the loop.

Comment: what is throwing me off in (a) is the d.. Should I just use d=2? Here is what I think it could be (without the d)::::
def is_prime(n):
  c=True
  while c:
    if n%2==0:
      c=True
    else:
      c=False
    if d<math.sqrt(n):
      c=True
    else:
      c=False
  if c==True:
   return n

Am I on the right track? Thanks joelt b/c I think that is what I was doing and just focusing on one helped.

Comment: @Callie, put that code in your question, and perhaps someone will undo the negative vote you received. (The code isn't correct, btw, but I'll wait until you edit your question to tell you why.)

Comment: Guess @Callie is not coming back?

Comment: @everyone Sorry I got into my programming. I [thought I] was on a roll.

Comment: `while n>1 and 2 < n**0.5:`
That's going to give you problems because you never change n you'll be looping forever if that initially evaluates true.

Comment: how do I change n then? I'm sorry but I really don't know what you mean and my prof. said it too but that makes no sense to me. . .

Comment: @kriegar Should I put the work outside the loop and after say 'while n<1 or 2>n**0.5: break' or something like that?

Comment: @Callie you want think of n as a constant... create another variable to compare against n... n is the number you want to check is prime or not, it wont change. n**0.5 is the limit you need to check up to. that also doesn't change. What is the property that makes a number prime? You can only divide a prime number evenly by 1 and itself. So you need to start at 2 and check if it divides into n, if not, increment the variable and check again. Continue until either the variable divides evenly into n (n not prime) or the variable is greater than the limit (as the directions indicate).

Comment: @kriegar I get what you're saying now, but we have not learned how to do incements other than for loops and I'm not sure how to apply a for loop until. I'm in CP 1, introduction. But I get what you're saying, I'm just not sure how to do it with my knowledge, you know? but I added d=2 as a start.

Comment: python increment is either `d += 1` or `d = d + 1`

Comment: @kriegar thank you. for right now I am saying goodnight, but I will keep messing with it because I want it to work! I'll post what I edited tomorrow sometime and I'll shoot you a notification to see what you think. But really, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about the big picture of the assignment being difficult. Just go step by step as the prof has broken it down.

Comment: my question is how to start it. this is how my mind is working::

Comment: @Callie Camper: Write a is_prime(n) function.  That's how you start it.

Comment: @Callie, the assignment tells you exactly how to start: "Do this with a loop that checks whether for any integer d, 1 < d < sqrt(n), d divides n."

Answer (score -1):

[**`Prime Number`**](http://Prime%20number)

> A prime number (or a prime) is a
>   natural number that has exactly two
>   distinct natural number divisors: 1
>   and itself.

**A)**

```
def is_prime(n):                 # Write a is_prime(n) function.
    if n <= 1:                   # It should accept a positive integer n>1 
        return False
    if n == 2:                   # 2 has 2 divisors 1 and itself satisfying definition
        return True
    i = 2                        # Start from 2 and check each number to the sqrt(n)
    while i < n**0.5:            # sqrt(n) can be written as n**0.5
        if n % i == 0:           # If n is divisible by i, which is not 1 or itself, 
            return False         #    return False (not prime)
        i+=1                     # Increment i by 1 and check looping condition
    return True                  # If loop breaks, return True (prime)
```

Primes can be discovered in a variety of ways. This is one of the most basic with the only optimisation being that the divisor to check is stopped at the root of n instead of checking every number to n.

**The most basic probably being:**

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

**B)**

```
def prime_sum(n):
    if n % 2 or n < 1:                          # if n is odd or less than 1 return invalid
        return "invalid input"
    p = 3
    while n-p > 0:
        if is_prime(p) and is_prime(n-p):       
            return (p, n-p)                     # if both conditions are met, return prime tuple
        p+=2                                    # only check odd numbers
    return "no answer found"
```

Comment: I have to question your pedagogical approach here. @Callie, I hope you don't just copy this without bothering to understand your error.

Comment: @senderle I'm not that stupid. Plus this is really advanced for my level so I'm taking the concept and trying to write it in my language. I think I got it (haven't tested it yet though).